# Unsubscribe Page on EXM 3.5 throwing 404

Tags: exm

I'm using Sitecore 8.2 update 5 and I'm having an issue with unsubscribe page.

When I click on the Unsubscribe link generated by EXM with redirectPage url:

> .../sitecore
>   modules/Web/EXM/RedirectUrlPage.aspx?ec_eq=eTdvBcWiA4b1cQPHOnBEhBBe2b4LHDlSaQsEm32D3QaxxCmzarXlhcI7ohNgDTHnFiMUrfsJStslV2YgyB2vZRhluh%2f7eFzZgSlrYXGyFFqPKPTGkoOekYTrgRB6WspV6qHmnjCWfS0Nj3jcv2DAL8S%2flzfM9va0AchGzczf6DokEsIZaINa%2fH8XJzfr4Nyumm2zo%2bO9Wqoa3I0OQbPjiLC3sjDBxTIR5ElmAY1QGb543BW%2fQZv0zHekZAkXXzJbaNOOH4lIANfHo0bEi0gA%2fpKoOKHW0eVMGQtoR40fmsS2F1U7Hh2pGk%2fNXdpUZGRn6ymohEC9%2b7Cxyz1g4kMUXQcMsO0AOX2YeDOwvOiQxhc%3d

After load on the page the website return 404..

> /404?item=%2fsitecore%2funsubscribe

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you running a multi server environment?  and if so, have the EXM files been deployed to the CD servers?

Comment: Was this an EXM upgrade?

Comment: Any errors in the EXM or Sitecore log files?

Comment: Are you running a multi server environment?  **- No, it's just one server. **EXM files been deployed to the CD servers? **- yes...**                                                 Any errors in the EXM or Sitecore log files? - **No, just on firefox network**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the problem.

when you create a unsubscribe link on EXM 3.5, you have to use '/sitecore modules/Web/EXM/Unsubscribe.aspx'.

EXM 3.4 (or less) use '/sitecore/Unsubscribe.aspx'.

Answer (score 0):

A while back I had a similar issue, however, in my case it was due to the Base URL field configured in EXM being incorrect.

See more info here :

https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/35/setting_up_exm/the_manager_root/the_manager_root_settings

https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/35/setting_up_exm/the_exm_default_settings

Comment: Hi @Adhir Ramjiawan, yes, it's right the url because the subscription confirmation and notification are working, just the unsubscribe is crashed.